# How to redirect using custom format routes in Rails?

Tags: ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm working on a simple app that requires me to redirect to a show action after the update action.

I have this route for show.

```
match '/user/:fullname' => 'items#show'
```

Which gives me this controller.

```
@user = User.find_by_fullname(params[:fullname])
```

However, after the update method of user,

```
def update
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    format.html { redirect_to @user } # Don't need to pass parameters here.
  else
    format.html { render action: 'edit' }
  end
end
```

It redirects me to the original format of show action which is:

```
sampleapp.dev/users/1
```

How can I redirect to show action using the format I specified in the routes.rb which is by fullname?

```
sampleapp.dev/users/johndoe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line to:

```
match '/user/:fullname' => 'items#show', :as => :custom_show_item
```

then change your redirect to:

```
redirect_to custom_show_item_path(:fullname => @user.fullname)
```